# How to display output on different screen in c?

Tags: c

I want to display output on different screen, but how?
For example: 
I want to display " hello world " on the first black screen, and when I press enter button, the old screen will disappear and another new black screen will display "thank you" . 
Just how to do that in c?

Comment: What do you mean by "screen"? C doesn't have any concepts of "screens". Do you mean different console windows?

Comment: Just see to clear command from bash, you can find the source code in repository.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want but just clear the screen after getting an enter.

`puts("\033[2J");` will work on most terminal using VT100 escape codes.

`clrscr()` is a nonstandard function defined in `<conio.h>` that some older compilers use.

`system("cls");` works with Windows and `system("clear");` with Linux and is in `<stdlib.h>`.

These options would cover most environments that you would encounter when using C.

Comment: clrscr is no longer available in <conio.h>. It's *very* old

Comment: @iBug `<conio.h>` is not standard so the creators can put what ever they like in there and take any thing out that they do not want or need. I do not think you can make a blanket claim that a function is no longer available. But is definitely very old.

Answer (score 0):

This is platform-dependent.

In Unix you have to call the corresponding APIs, Qt or GTK, to create a new terminal console.

In Windows you have to call WinAPI such as `CreateConsole` and such.

It would be easier if you only want to clear your current console. Using ASCII CSI escape sequence works on most Unix & Linux systems, just

```
printf("\x1B[2J");
```

Or in Windows, call

```
system("cls");
```

There's actually a more native approach which calls `FillConsoleOutputCharacter` and `FillConsoleOutputAttribute`, which introduces extra code that I'm not talking about here.

Comment: Thank you iBug, you are the best.